# GlassFish start-domain failed - Cannot launch my app in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, glassfish

I've a problem ! I couldn't found the answer. I hope you could help me.

I've installed GlassFish 4.1.2 and I've tried to test if it will work with this  command line : asadmin start-domain domain1 and I got this error :

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jQlv.png)

[Warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A11lH.png)

I can't understand why it doesn't work !

I tried also to configure GlassFish in my InteliJ to launch the app like that : 
[Config from IntelliJ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIwqI.png)

when I run the app I have Build success but while the deployment it still showing me : attempting to start domain domain1 ....

I'am working with JDK 1.8 as the picture show!

Before (last week) it worked for me and Now I don't know what is happening !!

Here is the log for the command line : asadmin start-domain domain1 --verbose

***PS : Am using Microsoft Windows [version 10.0.15063]***

```
C:\glassfish4\bin>asadmin start-domain domain1 --verbose
Command start-domain only accepts one operand
Usage: asadmin [asadmin-utility-options] start-domain
        [-v|--verbose[=<verbose(default:false)>]]
        [--upgrade[=<upgrade(default:false)>]]
        [-w|--watchdog[=<watchdog(default:false)>]]
        [-d|--debug[=<debug(default:false)>]]
        [-n|--dry-run[=<dry-run(default:false)>]]
        [--drop-interrupted-commands[=<drop-interrupted-commands(default:false)>]]
        [--domaindir <domaindir>] [-?|--help[=<help(default:false)>]]
        [domain_name]
Command start-domain failed.
```

Comment: Can you try starting Glassfish again using the **--verbose** parameter (**asadmin start-domain domain1 --verbose**) and then update your post with the log as text (not selective screen shots).

Comment: Thank you, I edited my post with the log text.

Comment: Oh, really thanks after doing asadmin start-domain domain1 --verbose. I tried again the command asadmin start-domain domain1 and it works !!!